# Check input based on checked status of sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JQuery code that navigates through a list of input checkboxes and checks the ones that do not have the property of `checked`

```
$('td input:checkbox.checkbox-excluded:not(:checked)', table).prop('checked', true).change();
```

I would like to add a second test so that I do not check the ones who have a sibling with the property of checked

Each table row has two checkboxes

```
> <td class=" downloaded"><input type="checkbox"
> class="checkbox-downloaded"></td><td class=" excluded"><input
> type="checkbox" class="checkbox-excluded"></td>
```

How do I check only the `checkbox-excluded` elements that are not checked AND their sibling `checkbox-downloaded` is also not checked?

Comment: Please attached table structure in html

Comment: @Mike Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.each()` and then `.siblings()`.
Also, it would be better if you scope the `$('td')` selector based on your hierarchy to improve performance.

```
$('td').each(function(i0,td){
    $(td).find('>input[type="checkbox"].checkbox-excluded:not(:checked)').each(function(i1,checkbox){
        if($(td).siblings().find('>input[type="checkbox"].checkbox-downloaded:not(:checked)').length>0)
        {
            $(checkbox).prop('checked', true).change();
        }
    });
});
```